# Swapping bytes of text in PHP

Tags: php

I basically need to port this piece of code to php

```
for (i = 0; i < 128/4; i++)
    data32[i] = bswap_32(data32[i]);
```

But, there is no bswap function in php.

Would someone be kind enough to provide me with something that could solve the problem?

Comment: What is `bswap_32`?  Where is the "text"?

Comment: Afaik, it's http://www.ee.surrey.ac.uk/CVSSP/Ravl/RavlDoc/share/doc/RAVL/Auto/Basic/Class/RavlN.bswap_32Obconst_int_AmpCb.html . As for the text, that is data32[i]

Comment: Hmm, yes, I guess I was assuming `char`, rather than `uint32_t` (presumably).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it (untested):

```
function bswap_32($j)
{
    return (($j & 255) << 24) | (($j & 0xff00) << 8) |
           (($j & 0xff0000) >> 8) | (($j & 0xff000000) >> 24);
}
```

Or, if there is a sign extension problem, this should resolve it:

```
function bswap_32($j)
{
    return (($j & 255) << 24) | (($j & 0xff00) << 8) |
           (($j & 0xff0000) >> 8) | (255 & (($j & 0xff000000) >> 24));
}
```

Comment: @Oli:  I don't expect there is any problem, but–just in case–I've amended as suggested.

Comment: If integer types are 32-bit on the OP's platform, then there will definitely be a problem (unless the OP's input values *never* have the msb set).

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like `bswap_32` is swapping [*endianness*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) of your 32-bit quantities.

I could just give you some code, but I'd prefer not to do people's work for them, so I'll explain the principle instead:

You can achieve that with bit-shifts and masks (so for instance, you need to mask out the 8 lowest bits, and shift them into the highest 8 bit positions of the result).

Shifting can be done with the `<<` and `>>` operators.  Masking can be done with the `&` operator.  See the [PHP manual page on operators](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.bitwise.php) for more details.